# Why can't I cast in generic class in realm-dotnet?

Tags: c#, realm, xamarin-studio

I use Realm dotnet.
I wrote the generic class for any object.

It is my generic class.

```
public class Controller<T> where T : RealmObject, new()
{
    private Realm realm;
    public Controller()
    {
        this.realm = Realm.GetInstance();
    }

    public void Insert(T selfObj)
    {
        this.realm.Write(() => 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(typeof(T)); // => "Country".


                // ERROR: System.InvalidCastException has been thrown Specified cast is not valid.
                var obj = this.realm.CreateObject<T>();

                // TODO: write later.
            }
    }
}
```

And model class is here.

```
public class Country : RealmObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And, I called like this.

```
    var cc = new Controller<Country>();
    Country newCon = new Country()
    {
        Name = "Japan"  
    };

    var newCon2 = new Country()
    {
        Name = "Korea"  
    };

    cc.Insert(newCon);
```

The
`System.InvalidCastException has been thrown Specified cast is not valid.`
error occurred.

My `Controller` class already known `T` is `Country` object.
Why `realm.CreateObject<T>();` can't cast?

Could you tell me how to fix.

Comment: hi, can you try this code Debug.WriteLine(typeof(selfObj));

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying. `Debug.WriteLine(typeof(selfObj)); ` was error. `selfObj Unknown identifier: selfObj` But, `Debug.WriteLine(selfObj.GetType());` said also `County`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

The issue was resolved via email. The real class `Country` descends from an intermediate `Model` class which descends in turn from `RealmObject`.

Currently we don't support inheritance in this manner. It is documented in our [help](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#model-inheritance).

We are probably going to move to using an interface instead of base class. There is a [git issue discussing this](https://waffle.io/realm/realm-dotnet/cards/573233f34471f81400d7a606).

**Original**

Firstly, I can't reproduce your exception with the current 0.76.1 release of Realm.

Using standalone objects like this works to a point. We don't yet support standalone objects which have relationships to other objects (see [this IList issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/287)).

One minor change to your code sample. To pass a `RealmObject` which is created standalone and copy it into a Realm, you can simply use `Manage`. eg:

```
public class Controller<T> where T : RealmObject, new()
{
    private Realm realm;
    public Controller()
    {
        this.realm = Realm.GetInstance();
    }

    public void Insert(T selfObj)
    {
        this.realm.Write(() => 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(typeof(T)); // => "Country".

                this.realm.Manage<T>(selfObj);
            }
        );  // closing paren was missing above too
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I forgot closing brace when I trimmed my snipped. I wrote your code, `this.realm.Manage<T>(selfObj)`. but `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error happened

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" sounds like a NullReferenceException. I'd need to see more code to understand why you got that - are you passing an uninitialised object into Insert?

Comment: The object I want to insert is `newCon`. It has `Name = "Japan"  
`. and it is instanced.

Comment: Please send a more complete example to help@realm.io so I can debug this. I can't work out what's happening from your explanation and the small amounts of code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In fact my Country has base class which extended from Realm. But I minimized code for question. I am going to send my complete code via email.